# django multiple databases django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I'm trying to store my celery tasks tables in `tasks` database which has nothing related with any other tables, but I keep getting this error.

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

I'd rather to not having extra tables which I don't use in celery tasks like users or my other models

so I made two abstract models for my databases:

```
class TaskModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        _db = 'tasks'

class CeleryTasks(TaskModel):
    ...


class DefaultModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        _db = 'default'

class MyDefaultDatabaseModel(DefaultModel):
     ...
```

and my database router looks like:

```
class DatabaseRouter:
    tasks_models = ['CeleryTasks']

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """ reading model based on params """
        if not hasattr(model, 'Meta'):
            return None
        return getattr(model.Meta, '_db', None)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """ writing model based on params """
        if not hasattr(model, 'Meta'):
            return None
        return getattr(model.Meta, '_db', None)

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if hasattr(obj1._meta, '_db') and hasattr(obj2._meta, '_db'):
            return obj1._meta._db == obj2._meta._db
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        print(
            f'allow migration database router invoked with args db={db},app_label={app_label},model_name={model_name},hints={hints}')
        if db == 'tasks':
            if model_name in self.tasks_models:
                print('returning True')
                return True
            print('returning False')
            return False
        print('returning None')
        return None
```

When I execute

> python manage.py migrate --database=tasks

and my full error logs may help:

```
allow migration database router invoked with args db=tasks,app_label=contenttypes,model_name=contenttype,hints={'model': <class '__fake__.ContentType'>}
returning False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 267, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 48, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    models.signals.post_migrate.send(
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/myhome/PycharmProjects/venv/iranPay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/constance/apps.py", line 28, in create_perm
    content_type, created = ContentType.objects.using(using).get_or_create(
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 573, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/myhome/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_content_type
``
```

Comment: which command you are executing?

Comment: can you confirm which value you are getting for db inside allow_migrate using pdb?

Comment: I printed all the args if you mean that @akashpagar

Comment: so in this case model_name=contenttype not in your class variable list, that is the reason its giving a false condition.

Comment: Because i dont want that table in my database unless its necessary @akashpagar